# Mongo Update Script

Tags: mongodb

I have a simple update script that for some reason goes through each document twice and proceeds to execute the code. I dont understand why this is happening...any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
db.products.find().forEach(function(product) {
var numerator = {
    0 : [],
    1 : [],
    2 : [],
    3 : [],
    4 : []
},
denominator= {
    0 : [],
    1 : [],
    2 : [],
    3 : [],
    4 : []
};

product.reviews.forEach(function(review) {
    var weight = review.weight.reputation + review.weight.reviewRelevance,
    i = 0;

    review.score.forEach(function(score) {
    if ( i == 0){
        score.rating = Math.ceil((score.rating/100) * 10);
    }else {
        score.rating = Math.ceil((score.rating/25) * 10);

        numerator[i].push(score.rating * weight);
        denominator[i].push(weight);
        i++;
        }
    });

    var s = 0;
    for (var key in product.score) {
        var obj = product.score[key];
        if ( key == 'Overall'){
            obj.percent = obj.rating;
            obj.rating = Math.ceil((obj.rating/100) * 10);
        }else {
        obj.rating = Math.ceil((obj.rating/25) * 10);
        }

                obj.info = {
        'numerator' : array_sum(numerator[s]),
        'denominator' : array_sum(denominator[s]),
        };

        s++;
    }
});
db.products.save(product);
});

function array_sum (array) {
    var key, sum = 0;

    if (array && typeof array === 'object' && array.change_key_case) { // Duck-type check for our own array()-created PHPJS_Array
            return array.sum.apply(array, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0));
      }

      // input sanitation
      if (typeof array !== 'object') {
          return null;
      }

      for (key in array) {
          if (!isNaN(parseFloat(array[key]))) {
                sum += parseFloat(array[key]);
          }
      }

      return sum;
}
```

Comment: try this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/snapshot/, (it does not mean that there is no error in your code), but can resolv your issue in some cases.

Comment: Thanks a bunch that worked, add an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the cursor does not handles the situation when you modify a document and it is moved to the end of the collection (it will be read again). You can use snapshoted cursor for this case to avoid multiple read of the several versions of the same document.

Check the documentation: [docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/snapshot](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/snapshot)